# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug' if I enable the proguard

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics

I get following error when I was running an app within Android Studio 2.

```
Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug'.
> Task with path 'dexDebug' not found in project ':app'.
BUILD FAILED
```

Here is the build.gradle for module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

The error is gone if I set the minfyEnabled to "false". But I do want it enabled.

Here is the build.gradle in project level.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The error is also gone if I replace "2.0.0-alpha3" to "1.3.1". But I do want "2.0.0" because I want the "Instant Run" feature.

Here is the gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
#Mon Dec 21 14:43:00 CST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Just run `flutter clean` and rebuild your app.

The issue came when a previous build was cancelled before completion. I didn't have to revert any of my dependencies.

Comment: try accepting the licences before building. checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue a few days ago and I found this thread [Twitter Developer Forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/solved-android-studio-2-0-cant-compile/57032) that points to some incompatibility with versions of gradle/build-tools/crashalics.

My problem was slightly different from yours as I'm not using `alpha-3` I'm using `1.5`. But on my update I also changed to the latest gradle distribution `gradle-2.9-all.zip`.

So probably/maybe you can fix it by changing to the latest gradle version.  But If it does not work, you'll really have to be patient and wait until `build tools V2.0` is not in alpha anymore **OR** the Crashalitycs team, fix the incompatibility.

Comment: I had the same problem and I updated to the latest version of Crashlytics (as of today it is `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.2` for the plugin and `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5` for the library, and that fixed the issue.  I am using the gradle android plugin `2.0.0-alpha3` (it also works with `1.5.0`).

Comment: You have to check if it is not because of the Proguard. You have to disable minify.

Comment: for me, disabling minify on debug works, and I'm still able to build my production app with minify enabled.

Answer (score 26):

Full combo of **build/ clean project** + **build/ rebuild project** + **file/ Invalidate caches / restart** works for me!

Comment: Please share the code for above

Comment: @heyom that's not code, those are options in the menu of the Android Studio (or IntelliJ) IDE

Comment: @acdcjunior you missed the joke

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me for Ionic v7 (Angular) + Capacitor I successfully built my .APK file

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue when integrating Firebase Cloud Store in my project.
Inside the project level gradle, I added

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can run this command in your project directory. Basically it just cleans the build and gradle.

```
   cd android && rm -R .gradle && cd app && rm -R build
```

In my case, I was using react-native using this as a script in package.json

```
"scripts": { "clean-android": "cd android && rm -R .gradle && cd app && rm -R build" }
```

Answer (score 5):

Running ./gradlew assembleDebug command on Android Studio Terminal had solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue, I resolved this by replacing dependencies in App level Build.gradle file

"""

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
androidTestImplementation 'com.androidx.support.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.androidx.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
```

BY

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.androidx.support.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.androidx.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
```

This resolves my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In place of **1.+** use the [latest version](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#crashlytics) of crashlytics -

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
```

you should use this way -

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:2.6.8'
        }
```

your problem will be resolved for sure.
**Happy coding !!**

Answer (score 3):

**build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go To Files>Settings>System Settings> Android SDK>
Enable **Android SDK Command-Line Tools (latest)** in **SDK Tools** and press OK.
[image: Step 1]

Then go to terminal and

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and accept all the licenses

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to fix:**

1. Run `flutter clean` in terminal.
2. Run your app again.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer in regards to what flutter is, etc. for users who do not have it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my project. I solved it by Downgrading my google-services version to 4.1.0 in my project's **build.gradle** file.

```
  buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' //decreased from 4.2.0
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with below error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

It started when I added below dependency in Gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.0.4'
```

I fixed it by upgrading the dependency version as below:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't specify the `sdk.dir` in my `local.properties` file

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by updating build.gradle like below:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sync sdk path with correct one

sdk.dir

Answer (score 0):

Upping SolArabhetty's answer, these steps worked for me:
1. Invalidating caches (Files -> Invalidate Caches)
2. Clean Project (Build -> Clean)
3. Re-build project (Build -> Rebuild Project)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was Android SDK PATHS needed to repath it. Doing `source ~/.bash_profile` fixed it.

In others' cases, it can be `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above has worked, check if you project is running on the correct Java version (SDK), changing the SDK to the correct one fixed the issue for me.

Here is how to change the project SDK if you are using IntelliJ:

1. Open Project Settings:
   Open your project in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Access Project Structure:
   Go to the "File" menu at the top left corner and select "Project Structure." Alternatively, you can use the shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S (or Cmd + ; on macOS).
3. Select Project:
   In the Project Structure dialog, on the left side, you'll see a list of settings. Select "Project" under "Project Settings."
4. View Project SDK:
   On the right side, you will see a section labeled "Project SDK." Here, you can see the Java version currently used for your project. It will display the path to the JDK and the Java version, such as "1.8" or "11."