# Whenever I run - Flutter build apk it gives me an error saying "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'."

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-build

It works completely fine while testing in debugging mode. But when i try to build the apk of this project I get this error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            3.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Have you tried similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421193/could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appcrashlyticsstoredeobsdebug-i) suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. I just restarted my pc and boom it was gone.