# why flutter_wallpaper_manager showing this error? Could not determine the dependencies of task ':flutter_wallpaper_manager:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My app\build.gradle file overview

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion\

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.flt_firebase"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
}
```

flutter_wallpaper_manager: ^0.0.3
flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0

`

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 130),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async{
      int location = WallpaperManager.BOTH_SCREEN;
      var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(imageurl[activeIndex]);
      final bool result =
          await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(file.path, location);
    },
```

`

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':flutter_wallpaper_manager:compileDebugAidl'.

> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-30

I'm Making Basic Wallpaper App for that I used the flutter_wallpaper_manager package and flutter_cache_manager but it gave me this runtime error.

Comment: did you run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include the complete Traceback.

Comment: You can run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did run flutter pub get.

Comment: I tried flutter clean still no change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug' if I enable the proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421193/could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appcrashlyticsstoredeobsdebug-i)

Comment: no,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421193/could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appcrashlyticsstoredeobsdebug-i

Answer (score 0):

You just need do this

```
flutter clean
/// and
flutter pub get
```

or not working then you can also downloading android 30 platform.
its Working Fine.

[image]

Comment: I already tried it.

Comment: so then please change both version its fine its work.

Comment: What does it mean (Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-30)

Comment: my problem got solved by downloading android 30 platform