# i am getting this error while running the app

Tags: reactjs, gradle, native

Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. .

> Could not determine the dependencies of null. > java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 16s.
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009483/17709311